# Why explicitly define variable as undefined?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

EDIT: In his own words: https://twitter.com/fogus/status/393058344413302784

I am reading Michael Fogus's "Functional JavaScript" and came across this listing at the beginning of chapter 5:

```
function dispatch(/* funs */) {
    var funs = _.toArray(arguments);
    var size = funs.length;

    return function(target /*, args */) {
        var ret = undefined; // <----------------------------------- ??
        var args = _.rest(arguments);

        for (var funIndex = 0; funIndex < size; funIndex++) {
            var fun = funs[funIndex];
            ret = fun.apply(fun, construct(target, args));

            if (existy(ret)) return ret;
        }

        return ret;
     };
}
```

If this is not a mistake, why does he explicitly define `ret` as `undefined`? And what are some more general reasons for doing this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: To set a default value? I'd go for `var ret` or `var ret = null`, but to each his own.

Comment: A very wild guess is that he favors a codying style where all variables are declared and initialized at the begining of the scope they are defined in. AFAIK there is no reason to do var ret = undefined. On the contrary, in older versions of ES, that would make the code vulnerable if undefined was redefined to something else.

Comment: @Tibos That's exactly what I explained in my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19544833/783743 =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One might do that just to make it clearer to readers that the value is undefined yet, or that he explicitly *wants* the value to be `undefined`.  That is, he's defining the value as `undefined`.

But there's no syntactic reason to do so; `var foo;` and `var foo = undefined;` do the same thing if they're at the beginning of a function, and using the latter anywhere else may well trash an existing variable's value.

Comment: This makes sense; my coworker said: "This a choice to tell the reader that undefined is a legitimate return value, and not an accidental failure to assign."

Comment: @ggundersen Hey, `undefined` may not actually be `undefined`. The author might be a sadist by deviously declaring `var ret = undefined;` where `undefined` might be some default value declared in a parent scope. You never know. Read my answer for more details: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19544833/783743

Answer (score 2):

The short answer to your question is to make things more explicit. I cannot vouch for the reason as to why the author defined `var ret = undefined;` because I am not the author. However I can explain why it is a good idea to be explicit when you're teaching something. Especially when you're teaching someone how to code.

One of my favorite articles is Bret Victor's famous blog post on [Learnable Programming](http://worrydream.com/LearnableProgramming/) (aside: you must read it - I insist). In this blog post Bret describes how people understand concrete examples better than abstract concepts. Hence by being explicit it's easier for a person with no prior experience with JavaScript to understand what's going on in the program.

Every self-proclaimed JavaScript programmer must know that declaring a variable but not defining it results in it being `undefined` (which is pretty obvious if you think about it). Hence it wouldn't make any difference whether the author wrote `var ret = undefined;` or simply `var ret;`. However the former is more concrete and more easily understood by newbies.

It should be noted however that `undefined` is not a reserved word in JavaScript. Hence you can create a variable called `undefined` which very well might not really be `undefined`. In the context of the code above `undefined` could actually not be `undefined` altogether. We don't know for sure because we can't see the lexical environment of `dispatch`. Nevertheless, in all probability it must be `undefined`.

Considering the above problem it would be less ambigous and more explicit to declare `ret` as `var ret = void 0;`. The `void` operator in JavaScript takes an expression and evaluates to `undefined`. Hence `void expression` always evaluates to `undefined`. However in the given context it would be less confusing and less ambigous to simply use `var ret;` which every sane JavaScript programmer does.

Of course, this is just my explanation in defense of the author's decision. For a more definitive answer you need to ask the author himself.

Comment: I find it ironic how you agree to how concrete/explicit things are easier to understand in comparison to abstract/implicit things but still bring up keyword resevation in the "lexical environment of dispatch" while explaining an otherwise much simpler question.
That said I do admire the thoroughness.

Answer (score 1):

In that specific case, I can't see a technical reason, it could be just an habit or a practice he has. Surely, he could just declare `ret` as follow:

```
var ret;
```

In that specific case, because the variable is local, would be enough. Also, it doesn't use the initial value of the variable for anything (in the loop it just assign it).

However, in a more complex environment, set the variable explicitly to `undefined`, can be a good practice. Because `var` doesn't declare a block scope variable, if you have a huge module or body function – or you work in a team, or you combine different scripts together before publish them on the web – it could be that you reuse the same variable's name twice, maybe in two different scope. In that case, if you don't explicitly set the value, you will reuse the value set previously. To make it clear:

```
var ret = 10;
/* doing something with ret */

/* in the same scope, some lines above: */

if (someCondition) {
   var ret;
   console.log(ret); // 10, not `undefined`
}
```

This is happening because the [hoisting](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting.html): the variable declaration are moved on top, and only the assignment are left. Because in the `if` block there is no assignment, and the variable is already declared, the declaration there would be simple removed.

Notice then, that the same code, without `var ret = 10` at the beginning would result in `undefined`: that's why could be error prone.

Comment: The problem with replacing your `var ret;` with `var ret = undefined;`, though, is that if the outer code isn't done with `ret` yet, too bad -- you've just overwritten its value.  This is why some people recommended declaring all your variables at the beginning of the function.  (I'd consider that a bit too rigid, but at the very least, one needs to understand variable scope in JS.)

Comment: Definitely. This is why we have `let`, now. A common scenario could be an `i` used for loop and something else, or some generic name like `sum`. In the most scenario I discussed (e.g. combine different files), usually you have finished with the variable; if you haven't it's unlikely that you're reusing the same name – of course, a mistake can always happen. The problem with `var` is that you have the "feeling" that if you declare in blocks (`if`, `for`…) it's "limited" to them, but it's not.